# Xamarin.Android .Jar Binding --> Where do i find the using directive for the MainActivity.cs file?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, jar, binding

I want to include a Github project into my Xamarin.Android project.
The Github project is in Java and offers a download as .jar file.

I am fine with the Jarbinding, as it is described well in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar), but when it comes to using the bound .jar file I am struggeling. In the microsoft docs one includes the "*Picasso-2-x-x.jar*" file by setting the *using* directive "*using Com.Squareup.Picasso;*" in the "*MainActivity.cs*" file.

Where can i find the correct using directive for my .jar file? Please help me out.

Link to the Github project i want to use: [Multislider](https://github.com/apptik/MultiSlider).

Comment: You should know which .jar file you want to use, then binding .jar file according to [Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar). If you want to make sure the binding was successful. When you reference a project, you can double click the reference to open up the Object Browser, and view the classes and methods available.

Comment: There aren't any classes or methods in the object browser...: https://ibb.co/0ZhVBfM
That's the .jar file i want to use: https://ibb.co/KyxmsDw

Comment: From your .jar file link, I don't see any .jar file.